# I want to use a image from public/images folder as body background, but it is giving me error

Tags: css, reactjs, path, background-image

Not rendering background image and showing error.
 Is there a way to render the image ?

```
Failed to compile
./src/App.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-oneOf-4-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/App.css)
Error: Can't resolve '/images/a.png' in 'C:\Users\ankus\Desktop\test1\src'
```

#### Folder Structure

```
+---public
ª   ª   favicon.ico
ª   ª   index.html
ª   ª   logo512.png
ª   ª   manifest.json
ª   ª   robots.txt
ª   ª   
ª   +---images
ª           a.png
ª           
+---src
        App.css
        App.js
        index.js
```

##### App.css file

```
body {
  background-image: url('/images/a.png');
}
```

Comment: You are bundling using webpack?

Comment: This might help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35369419/how-to-use-images-in-css-with-webpack