# Resolving css background-image url with Webpack

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, frontend

I am using webpack and simply trying to apply a `background-image` specified in a `url` property to an html element.

I've looked at several threads ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288886/webpack-background-images-not-loading) for instance) but did not find something that works for me.

Here's my setup :

// index.js

```js
import React from 'react'
import styles from './styles.css'

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className={styles.container}></div>
  )
}

export default MyComponent
```

// styles.css

```css
.container {
  background-image: url('../../../static/public/images/my-background.jpg');
}
```

// webpack.config.js

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "index.bundle.js"
  },
  mode: process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development',
  resolve: { 
    modules: [path.resolve(__dirname, "src"), "node_modules"],
  },
  devServer: {
    static: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.html"),
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [
        {
          from: 'static',
          to: 'static'
        }
      ]
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
        { 
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, 
            exclude: /node_modules/, 
            use: ["babel-loader"] 
        },
        {
            test: /\.(css)$/,
            use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
        },
        {
          test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|gif)$/,
          use: ['url-loader', 'file-loader'],
        },
    ],
},
}
```

When reaching localhost I do see the path being resolved :
[image]

However, when I try to reach that url, all I see is a little white square ...

[image]

This is definitely not the image. I do find the image present in my build in `./dist/static/public/images/my-background.jpg`

Note that the image has a large size : 3842 × 2162

I think this has to do with webpack loader configuration, but did not quite find how to adjust it to get it to work here. Any help would be very appreciated !

Comment: Try `{
          test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|gif)$/,
          type: 'asset/resource',
        },` instead.

Comment: EDIT: Thanks a lot. Just tried with 
`{
          test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|gif)$/,
          type: 'asset/resource',
        },`

And it did show the image. 

Could you explain to me why I need to be removing loaders here :O seems all examples I seen online where using those. XD

Comment: You're welcome.. basically you are may be using a new version of webpack, where url-loader and file-loader are deprecated and Asset Modules are introduced. I'll put it in an answer :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are may be using a new version of Webpack, where `url-loader` and `file-loader` are deprecated and `Asset Modules` are the alternatives.

Try using:

```
{
      test: /\.(jpg|png|svg|gif)$/,
      type: 'asset/resource',
},
```

instead.

For more information [click here](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/).

Comment: For anyone who googles this, I am using webpack : 5.62.1. Thanks a lot @SomoKRoceS !

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and it finally worked by using `~` to reference the project directory and access `public` folder from there.

```
background-image: url("~/public/images/person.png");
```

And this is working fine for me :)

**OR** And the other alternative would be to move your images to the `src` directory, webpack will pack them in a folder called `static/media` as static files

Answer (score 1):

The solution (using a webpack version prior to 5.0) is to turn off `css-loader`'s URL parsing, because the CSS file isn't updating the URL string when webpack builds

```js
module.exports = { 
      ...
     module: {
        rules: [ 
            { //https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/
                test: /\.css$/, 
                use: ["style-loader"]
            },

            { //https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/
                test: /\.css$/, 
                loader: "css-loader",
                options: {
                    url: false,
                }
            }
        ]
    }

}
```

Note that this will make so that the files used in .css will not be hashed and will be structured like the original /public/ folder upon building the project to the /dist/ folder. Which is what makes it work.

For reference see [this github issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/256#issuecomment-288460824) and [this one](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/1380)

Also, I'm using:

- "css-loader": "^6.7.2",
- "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
- "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
- "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
- "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
- "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
- "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.1"

Update: Having a rule object that uses 'url-loader' might override out files from the other rules. So, in that case you should remove it and have the options in the 'css-loader' like so:

```
{ 
    test: /\.css$/, 
    loader: "css-loader",
    options: {
        url: true,
        esModule: false
    }
}
```

Try commenting out each option and rules and see the results to check what each option and rule is doing. Delete the .dist/ folder before each build (because it's not automatically clean after each build) to make sure you know what files are produced and when.

Answer (score 1):

I had just upgraded from webpack v4 to v5 and, as per the webpack docs on [asset management for images](https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-management/#loading-images), I had to make sure the images in the css files were actually currently located where I was saying they were and not where they will be.

So, changing from:

```
...
background: url(/static/images/header.jpg)
...
```

to:

```
...
background: url(/images/header.jpg)
...
```

everywhere fixed this issue for me.